# Javascript setTimeout issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a bar that shows up (in rails) from a flash hash. I want it to explode with jquery, so I added this code:

```
<script>
setTimeout("derp()", 2000);

function derp() {
     $("span").hide("explode", { pieces: 16 }, 500);
}

</script>
```

Works fine except in a couple of seconds it appears again and then something extremely strange happens - the path to googleapis is shown and the page becomes barely responsive. What gives?

Comment: You should just pass a reference to `derp()` to `setTimeout()`.

Comment: How many `span` elements do you have on the page?

Comment: show us more code, are you sure this is the part that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the proper way of using setTimeout

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 

    setTimeout(function () {
      $("span").hide("explode",{ pieces: 16 }, 500); 
    }, 2000);  

</script>
```

running it the way you had is like using eval(), you should avoid passing a string in setTimeout()

you could also pass your function like this:

```
setTimeout(derp,500);
```

Comment: Though this is indeed how it should be called, I'm not certain whether this is the actual cause of his problem.

Comment: @Vlad Did this actually fix the problem?  While I agree with it, I don't see how this caused what was described.  I would be very interested to understand if it did.

Comment: Yep it did fix the problem. I had the <script> inside of the <span> and as soon as I took it out all was well so I guess I just needed a prod in the right direction